# Which keymap should I use for a wired Mac keyboard in Gentoo Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gentoo, keymap

I just purchase the new wired Mac keyboard:

[image]

Running on Gentoo Linux it works mostly fine. The only problem I am having is the function keys and swapping the Alt and Command keys to resemble a regular PC keyboard. When I tried switching to the "mac-us" keymap in `/etc/conf.d/keymaps` I got garbage when typing (not even qwerty).

Are there any specific keymaps I can use to get what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if this will work for Gentoo, but it might if you are using xmodmap. I found a fix that worked on Fedora 14 for me from the [Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard):

To fix the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key issue, I did the following:

```
$ sudo bash
# echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
# exit
```

I added the following to `~/.Xmodmap` to switch the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> keys:

```
! Swap Alt and Cmd keys.
keycode 37 =    Control_L
keycode 133 =   Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 64 =    Super_L
keycode 108 =   Super_R
keycode 134 =   ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key
keycode 105 =   Control_R       Multi_key
clear Shift
clear Lock
clear Control
clear Mod1
clear Mod2
clear Mod3
clear Mod4
clear Mod5
add    Shift   = Shift_L Shift_R
add    Lock    = Caps_Lock
add    Control = Control_L Control_R
add    Mod1    = Alt_L 0x007D
add    Mod2    = Num_Lock
add    Mod4    = Super_L Super_R
add    Mod5    = Mode_switch ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift

! Configure '=' key on numpad as '='.
keycode 0x7D =  equal
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the normal keymap type (us/pc104) and use xmodmap or a XkbOptions setting in your xorg.conf to swap the alt and command keys. Read [xmodmap](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xmodmap/) for the first and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

X or console?
Probably the former. If yes, you can set more than just a keymap:

- layout
- model
- variant
- options

the model should match yours so just go through the list.
a variant is to customize it further, ex., set a compose key.
options can be "no dead keys" etc.
Woth such you should be able to configure it (almost?) perfectly.